# How to use Entity Framework and OData in vNext MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is there any way to use Entity Framework in vNext MVC 6 (in the current release). Well, I found no option in "Add new item" of VS14 ctp and if we do manually there is some DB update problems (as i tried in earlier versions) and whats the neuget package available for Entity Framework and oData and how to use them. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not yet support for OData in ASP.NET vNext, but there is a new version of Entity Framework: EF7. You can learn more about getting started with Entity Framework 7 here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki